# UI becomes unresponsive when device is rotated in increments of 180º

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a really strange issue here. One of my testers found when they rotate my device in increments of 180 degrees the device UI will stop responding (not crash), but when rotated by 90 degrees, it works fine.

After some exploration with the Reveal app I found that after the app becomes responsive, a UISnapshotView is covering my UI, when I tell that layer to hide, I find that my app is still working fine behind it.

I am not creating that layer, and I believe its the layer that iOS uses to animate transitions and rotations. So my question is, what could be happening to cause that layer to get stuck, and only get stuck when you rotate 180 degrees (ie. flip the device to the opposite orientation.)

I do not do any custom animations, and I have no code being called on rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was related to some code I found to remove the rounded corners on the split-view in-case anyone else has this problem.